# Can someone explain this "kth smallest integer in an unsorted array" code? - C

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting, element

I basically have to write a function that takes in an array, an int n that indicates elements in array and int k which is the kth smallest int in the array (not kth smallest position). The array is not allowed to be modified (sorted). I've spent a while trying to get my head around this solution but I keep confusing myself.

Can someone try and explain it to me? Thanks!

```
int
kth_smallest(int A[], int n, int k) {
    int i, j;
    int smaller, equal;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        smaller = 0;
        equal = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            smaller += (A[j] < A[i]);
            equal += (A[j] == A[i]);
        }
        if (smaller <= k && k < smaller + equal) {
            return A[i];
        }
    }
    printf("No %d'th smallest possible in array of %d items\n", k, n);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Here is the step out solution that I calculated for some test data.

```
A[4] = {1,1,4,3} | n = 4 | k = 3 | Expected outcome = 4

    Loop 1 (A[i] = 1) :
    smaller = 0.
    equal   = 2.

    test: smaller <= k && k < smaller+equal | 0 <= 3 && 3 < 2 | FALSE

    Loop 2 (A[i] = 1):
    smaller = 0.
    equal   = 2.

    test: smaller <= k && k < smaller+equal | 0 <= 3 && 3 < 2 | FALSE

    Loop 3 (A[i] = 4):
    smaller = 3.
    equal   = 1.

    test: smaller <= k && k < smaller+equal | 3 <= 3 && 3 < 4 | TRUE

    RETURN A[i] (=4). (Which matches expected)

    Third smallest int in A is 4, with 1 and 3 before it.
```

Comment: This is an `O(n^2)` solution. It is simple, and may be the right solution for your use-case if `n` is reasonably small. If you get into time trouble for large `n`, look into [Median of medians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tip: In understanding such algorithms it's often helpful to consider the basic (and corner) cases first. Start by assuming all elements in the array are distinct. Then by the time you get to the 'if' clause, 'smaller' = num of elements smaller than current inspected element (A[i]) and 'equal' = 1. So the 'if' clause becomes:

```
if (smaller <= k && k < smaller + 1)
```

which necessarily means

```
smaller = k
```

so by returning A[i] you are returning the element that has (k-1) smaller elements in the array (because 'k' is a 0-based index), i.e. the k-th smallest element, as expected. Now look at an example where all elements are equal. smaller = 0 and equal = n (always). so any 'k' in the range 0..n-1 will return the single number in the array, again, as expected. Now consider your example again and see if you can make better sense of it. Good luck!

Comment: Thats mate! It makes sense now!